# Laravel5 Facade not resolved

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I've registered a service provider in `config/app.php`, it's being loaded and executed.

In the service provider register() method:

```
\App::bind("timer", function() { 
    return new Foo\Utils\Timer(); 
});
```

Next, i have created the facade like this

```
<?php namespace Foo\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Timer extends Facade {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'timer'; }
}
```

Next, i've added the facade implementation

```
<?php namespace Foo\Utils;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Timer {
    function test() {}
}
```

Finally, i've added the alias in `config/app.php`

```
'Timer' => 'Foo\Facades\Timer'
```

When i do

```
\Timer::test();
```

i get the following

```
exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class timer does not exist'
```

Whats wrong?

**EDIT**

`Foo\Facades\Timer` is being loaded properly.

Also, `Foo\Utils\Timer` is being resolved since i am able to do

```
$timer = new Foo\Utils\Timer();
$timer->test();
```

without any errors.

Comment: Is Foo\Facades defined in the autoload classmap in composer.json?

Comment: No, it's defined with psr-4 autoload - however, the Foo\Facade class is being loaded because it's properly returning the "timer" value

Comment: And you've registered the service provider?

Comment: Yes i did. Like i said, i know the service provider is running because it performs other actions too - and i can Log::debug() just before the App::bind() instruction.

Comment: Hmm are you importing with?

use Foo\Utils\Timer;

Comment: Silly question, but... Do you load your service provider ?